# Get diffuse map RGB data from Qt3D PickEvent

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, qt3d

I am developing an application using Qt3D's Scene3D components. I have loaded a mesh obj into the `Scene3D` and applying a PNG image as diffuse map via `QDiffuseMapMaterial`. Great so far, object renders with map correct.

Now, I need to get the RGB properties for a picked vertex using a `QPickEvent`. I aquire a few vertex properties like so:

```
ESEctoPoint ES3DAnalysisEntity::getVertexDataFromIndex(quint32 idx)
{
    ESEctoPoint vData;
    vData.vIndex = idx;

    const QGeometry *geometry = m_mesh->geometry();
    for (QAttribute* attribute : geometry->attributes())
    {
        if (attribute->name() == defaultTextureCoordinateAttributeName())
        {
            vData.vTexCoord = extractVertexData<QVector2D, uint>(attribute, idx);
        }
...
    }

    return vData;
}
```

I then have the vertex index, position, and uv texture coordinates. Now, what I need is the RGB data from the uv position for the given vertex. How do I go about getting that data? I am keeping the diffuse material and the `QTextureImage` containing the diffuse map in memory. I'm sure there's a way to get the RGB value, I just need a little help with how to translate the uv texture coordinate to QTextureImage and get the pixel data.

**FOLLOWUP**

Using the answer given, I am holding the image in a `QImage` object, I get the vertex position, followed by texture coordinates. Using the texture coordinates, I am able to get the pixel position and the pixel's color using this small function:

```
QColor getPixelColorForTexturePos(QVector2D const& uvPos, QImage* map)
{
    auto x = uvPos.x() * map->width();
    auto y = map->height() - (uvPos.y() * map->height());
    return map->pixelColor((int)x, (int)y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QTextureImage` does not hold the image data itself, it just holds information about the texture that was uploaded to OpenGL.

It is possible to get the texture data back with raw OpenGL. There is probably some way to do it using Qt too, but I would not recommend it. Copying data between GPU and CPU is slow, so better to avoid it if not necessary.

I would recommend to keep the texture loaded in a `QImage`, then you can easily query to pixel colors using `pixel(..)` or `pixelColor(..)` methods. It may seem wasteful to have it loaded twice, but if you need to access the pixel data from CPU, there is no better way.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense if `QTextureImage` doesn't hold the image data itself. Do you know, would the texture coordinates map directly to the pixel position in the `QImage`?

Comment: No, texture coordinates range from 0.0 to 1.0 starting at bottom left corner. `QImage` uses regular pixel coordinates from 0 to width/height starting at top left corner. So you have to multiply by width and height, flip Y axis and round.

Comment: It is also possible for texture coordinates to be out of the [0.0, 1.0] range. In that case OpenGL wraps or clamps them (wraps by default), so if your mesh data may contain such coordinates, you need to wrap/clamp them as well.